# Visibility scope - global variables

Tags: php

It's a visibility scope issue. Can I make the variables global?

For some reason within main.php,

```
echo '<div class="header"><div class="counts">'.$displaycount.' </div><h5>.$LANG_MEMBERS_ONLINE_NOW.' ?></h5></div>';
```

isn't displaying. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes. Code here for posterity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP functions will only use local copies of variables unless you explicitly tell it to use the global versions.

There are two ways of doing this:

Access it as `$GLOBALS['LANG_MEMBERS_ONLINE_NOW']` everywhere you use it or put `global $LANG_MEMBERS_ONLINE_NOW;` at the top of the function.

Edit: It would also work with `$displaycount` (as `$GLOBALS['displaycount']`), but for whatever reason, I assumed `$LANG_MEMBERS_ONLINE_NOW` was the only global when I posted this.  Whoops.

Comment: Turns out in lang.en.php, define doesn't work. Used $ to declare variable instead. Now it appears! Removing link as well.